# Windows batch compair two path directories and write out the difference

Tags: batch-file, compare, dir

I want to parse a directory and when new files show up it shoud be listed in a queue for a other batch.

I tried it like that:

```
@echo off
:START
set ftpdir=Z:\FTP\home\
set xdir=Z:\NewDir\
set vtree=v.txt
set vtreecomp=vcomp.txt

if not exist %vtree% (dir %ftpdir% /S/B > %vtree%) else ( goto VCOMPTREE )
exit

:VCOMPTREE
dir %ftpdir% /S/B > %vtreecomp%
fc %vtree% %vtreecomp% > nul
if errorlevel 1 fc %vtree% %vtreecomp% >> queue.txt & exit 
goto START
```

But i don't get only the different lines.
What i get:

```
Vergleichen der Dateien v.txt und VCOMP.txt
***** v.txt
Z:\FTP\home\22.10.2013 #111
Z:\FTP\home\23.10.2013 #222
***** VCOMP.txt
Z:\FTP\home\22.10.2013 #111
Z:\FTP\home\22.10.2013 #111 - Kopie
Z:\FTP\home\23.10.2013 #222
*****

***** v.txt
***** VCOMP.txt
Z:\FTP\home\23.10.2013 #222 - Kopie
*****
```

What i want:

```
Z:\FTP\home\22.10.2013 #111 - Kopie
Z:\FTP\home\23.10.2013 #222 - Kopie
```

Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fc` command output show the differences in sets that include the first and last equal lines. If you want to get just the different lines, you must achieve the comparison of the files by yourself. The Batch program below do that:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set ftpdir=Z:\FTP\home\
set xdir=Z:\NewDir\
set vtree=v.txt
set vtreecomp=vcomp.txt

:START
if not exist %vtree% dir %ftpdir% /S/B > %vtree%

:VCOMPTREE
dir %ftpdir% /S/B > %vtreecomp%
fc %vtree% %vtreecomp% > nul
if errorlevel 1 (
   set "vtreeLine="
   < %vtree% (
   for /F "delims=" %%a in (%vtreecomp%) do (
      if not defined vtreeLine set /P vtreeLine=
      if "!vtreeLine!" equ "%%a" (
         set "vtreeLine="
      ) else (
         echo %%a
      )
   )) > queue.txt
   exit
)
goto START
```

This program just manage the case when new files are added to previous tree; it will fail if any file is *deleted*.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how this is related to bash, because it looks like a Windows batch file. If you only want to do what you say at the start, try using ROBOCOPY to only copy new files.

Comment: I didn't know that comand. But there is a problem. The directory where the files shoud be copied to has a other structure.
ROBOCOPY seems to only mirror two directories and can't just give me a list of the changes. The File with the diffrences in it shoud function like a queue for a other batch (copy batch).
And yes, only windows batch (typed wrong).

Comment: robocopy source target /l /mir /fp /ns /nc /ndl /njh /njs